# Can you use MySQL @ session variables in the C# connector?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, mysql-connector

I have a query that utilizes MySQL session variables (note the @rank variable)

```
SELECT Rank, UserId, CurrentVDOT
FROM
    (
        SELECT @rank := @rank + 1 AS Rank, UserId, MaxVDOT AS CurrentVDOT
        FROM
            (
                SELECT UserId, MAX(VDOT) AS MaxVDOT
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT U.UserId, U.VDOT
                        FROM
                            (
                                SELECT UserId, MAX(Created) AS Created
                                FROM UserVDOT
                                GROUP BY UserId
                            ) G
                        INNER JOIN UserVDOT U
                        ON U.UserId = G.UserId
                            AND U.Created = G.Created
                    ) M
                GROUP BY UserId
                ORDER BY MaxVDOT DESC
            ) R, (SELECT @rank := 0) foo
    ) F
WHERE F.UserId = @UserId;
```

If I try to execute this against the C# MySQL connector, it tries to tell me that I need to declare @rank as an input parameter variable.

Is there any way around this?

Thanks.

Comment: Typically, when using '@something' C# will think you are trying to create a [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx).  Is there another way you can declare a session variable in MySQL?  More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sessionparameter.aspx) too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **Hello Allison!**
>
> I was facing the same problem recently, but I found that by default,
>   the SQL connection disables the use of variables in queries. To solve
>   this problem you can enable the connection string as follows:

Connection String:

```
server=192.168.0.0;password=root;User Id=root;Persist Security Info=True;database=my_db;Allow User Variables=True
```

You must enter connection parameter **Allow User Variables=True** to make it work.

> I hope I've helped.
>
> ***Hiago Takaki***

Answer (score 3):

There is another way if you don't want to make the change global by setting the connection string.

This can be done by surrounding the name with single quotes `'` like the following.

```
SELECT Rank, UserId, CurrentVDOT
FROM
    (
        SELECT @'rank' := @'rank' + 1 AS Rank, UserId, MaxVDOT AS CurrentVDOT
        FROM
            (
                SELECT UserId, MAX(VDOT) AS MaxVDOT
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT U.UserId, U.VDOT
                        FROM
                            (
                                SELECT UserId, MAX(Created) AS Created
                                FROM UserVDOT
                                GROUP BY UserId
                            ) G
                        INNER JOIN UserVDOT U
                        ON U.UserId = G.UserId
                            AND U.Created = G.Created
                    ) M
                GROUP BY UserId
                ORDER BY MaxVDOT DESC
            ) R, (SELECT @'rank' := 0) foo
    ) F
WHERE F.UserId = @UserId;
```

It will now be treated as a session variable.