# Executing sql file with multiple statements

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm wanting to execute a bunch of sql files and I'm having problems with (i think) files that have multiple statements in them. See here:

http://pastebin.com/yenknuq6

Trying to execute this sql throws this exception:

> "at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()"

I'm using MySql connectors and I'm not doing any modification to the strings and just reading them from file.

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection())
{
    try
    {
        conn.ConnectionString = connect_str;
        conn.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("\n[EXECUTING] " + file);
        String sql = File.ReadAllText(file);
        if (sql != null && !sql.Equals(""))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(sql);
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
            command.CommandText = sql;
            command.Prepare();

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("no sql");

        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[SQL EXCEPTION] " + e.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is the `@` characters in the script which are mistaken as parameters.  I imagine that the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348028/) will help you.

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You must enter connection parameter Allow User Variables=True to make it work.