# MySQL SELECT INTO Variable, Getting 'Fatal Error encountered during command execution.'

Tags: c#, mysql

I have tried MANY suggested solutions from here but nothing seems to work for this problem.  I just keep getting this error message when it hits the 'mdr = command.ExecuteReader();' line.  Any thoughts please?

```
 try
            {
                MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";");
                MySqlCommand command;
                MySqlDataReader mdr;

                connection.Open();

                string ThePID = tbPID.Text;
                string TheRound = tbRound.Text;
                string CurrentPage = tbCurrentPage.Text;

               // SELECT @myvar:= myvalue

                string query = "SELECT ImageURL, ProofingText " +
                    "INTO @ImageURL, @ProofingText " +
                    "FROM Rounds " +
                    "WHERE ProjectID = " + ThePID + " " +
                    "AND CurrentRound = "  + TheRound + " " +
                    "AND Page = " + CurrentPage + ";";


                command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
                mdr = command.ExecuteReader();

                mdr.Read();

                rtProofing.Text = mdr.GetString("@PRoofingText");
                    tbURL.Text = mdr.GetString("@ImageURL");
                    tbImagePage.Text = Path.GetFileName(tbURL.Text);
                    PageBox.Image = Image.FromFile(tbURL.Text);

                    connection.Close();
                    connection.Dispose();
            }


            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

            }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. Also add the complete error message you get, maybe even show the full stack trace and error message of the exception itself.

Comment: Did you try putting `tbURL.Text = mdr.GetString("@ImageURL");`, before `rtProofing.Text = mdr.GetString("@PRoofingText");` ?

Comment: Please include the _full_ exception message and call stack in your question: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Comment: Gluing data - especially user input - into a string is the wrong way to build SQL.  NET has provided SQL parameters for a very long time.  Nor is that a good way to build a connection string

Comment: An insert into two session Variable doesn't make any sense in your query,  see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17030397/5193536 and please use **prepared statement**

Comment: You have the entire error message. You have the entire block of code that has the problem in it.  I have pointed out where the code fails when I tried to execute it.  I am working alone here with no one else to ask questions.  Most all question I work out on my own using suggestion here on the site.

Comment: No, we _don't_ have the full error message or call stack that I asked for. Please read http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/, follow what it tells you to do, and edit the details into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/), you will get a helpful exception message that explains the problem:

> Parameter '@ImageURL' must be defined. To use this as a variable, set 'Allow User Variables=true' in the connection string.

By default, MySQL queries (executed from .NET) can't use user-defined variables. You can relax this limitation by adding `Allow User Variables=true` to your connection string.

However, this won't fix your underlying problem, which is that this isn't the right way to select data from MySQL.

Firstly, your query is susceptible to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection); you should rewrite it to use parameters as follows:

```cs
using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = @"SELECT ImageURL, ProofingText
        FROM Rounds
        WHERE ProjectID = @ThePID
        AND CurrentRound = @TheRound
        AND Page = @CurrentPage;";
    commands.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ThePID", ThePID);
    commands.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TheRound", TheRound);
    commands.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrentPage", CurrentPage);
```

Then, you can retrieve the values with a slight variation on your current code. You must retrieve the values by their column names, which do not have a leading `@`. You should also check that a row was retrieved by examining the return value of `Read()`:

```cs
if (mdr.Read())
{
    rtProofing.Text = mdr.GetString("ProofingText");
    tbURL.Text = mdr.GetString("ImageURL");
}
```

Finally, string concatenation is also not the right way to build a connection string. The `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder` class exists for this purpose; use it.

```cs
var builder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
{
    Server = server,
    Database = database,
    UserID = uid,
    Password = password,
};
using var connection = new MySqlConnection(csb.ConnectionString);
```

Comment: You have just helped me to solve my issue with user-defined variables in creating MariaDB proc by my app. "Allow User Variables=true" did the trick. Thanks!